# ESP32 UART interrupt every character

Tags: c++, interrupt, esp32, uart, isr

Is there a way to generate an uart interrupt on an ESP32 as soon as a single character has been received?

I know you can generate an [interrupt](https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/blob/3082fc79113c7369f7bfd7ab04f36bce03b956b6/examples/peripherals/uart/uart_events/main/uart_events_example_main.c) when the whole message has been received, or on a specific pattern, buffer overflows, errors, etc., but I am looking for a (simple) way to this on a per character basis.

Comment: I recommend you either add the "esp-idf" or "arduino" tag to indicate what framework you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're working with ESP IDF, you can configure the [UART interrupts](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-reference/peripherals/uart.html#using-interrupts) to trigger from a [RX threshold](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-reference/peripherals/uart.html#_CPPv418uart_intr_config_t) of a single byte quite easily. Omitting all error handling:

```
uart_intr_config_t uintr_cfg = {.rxfifo_full_thresh = 1};
uart_intr_config(UART_NUM_x, &uintr_cfg);
uart_enable_rx_intr(UART_NUM_x);
```